# Prove $X$ has the weak topology where $p:X\to Y$ is a covering map.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, cw-complexes, weak-topology

This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180508/coverings-of-cw-complexes-are-also-cw-complexes-how-do-i-show-that-it-has-the-w), but the method used is different than the one I learned in my algebraic topology course, which I believe I should use. I showed that given that $Y$ is a CW complex (satisfies characteristic map axiom, closure finiteness, and weak topology axioms), the characteristic map $f: D_\alpha^k\to Y$ lifts to a map $\tilde{f}: D_\alpha^k\to X$ which satisfies the characteristic map axiom, so the cells are $e = \tilde{f}(int(D^k_\alpha))$. Now I want to show that $A\subseteq X$ is closed iff $A\cap \bar{e} = A\cap \tilde{f}(D^k_\alpha)$ is closed, which is my definition of weak topology. The forward direction is simple, both $A$ and $\bar{e}$ are closed so their intersection is closed.

The reverse direction is giving me trouble. I want to use the fact that $p$ restricted to certain open sets gives a homeomorphism, and if I show $A\cap \bar{e}$ is in one of such sets, then it should be closed since $f(D^k_\alpha)$ is also closed (or something along those lines). Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I believe your definition of weak topology is the same as the one in the linked answer. Your definition is: $A$ is closed iff $A \cap \tilde{f}(D_\alpha^k)$ is closed for all $\alpha$. The other definition is: $A$ is closed iff $\tilde{f}^{-1}(A)$ is closed for all $\alpha$. But note that $A \cap \tilde{f}(D_\alpha^k)$ is closed iff $\tilde{f}^{-1}(A)$ is closed since $\tilde{f}$ is a quotient map onto its image.